# Practical ways to tell if a Chrome extension is safe?

Tags: chrome, trust, browser-extensions

After reading about [Emails a browser extension developer gets from scammers](https://sponsor.ajay.app/emails/) (and the comments [here](https://news.ycombinator.com/item?id=25884338)) I understand that there are people who try to convince good addon developers to introduce shady (or outright malicious) code into their extensions.

This means that the users of addons have to be ***extremely*** careful to make sure they trust what they're installing. However, people still install addons all the time without thinking.

What checks can a layperson carry out to improve the odds that the addon is not exploiting them? For example, are there any lists or databases that review Chrome extensions' source code, so a layperson can look up the addon's reviews (e.g. similar to review sites like rotten tomatoes or goodreads)? And are there any other simple and effective ways to be able to trust a Chrome extension?

Comment: Not much unless you are willing to go through code,best you can do is only install ones that you trust or is from some big names which has a reputation to maintain and even then you have to hope they don't get breached.

Comment: @yeah_well do you know if any organisations combine efforts to do that? Perhaps just for the most popular extensions? I would be quite trusting if an open community of security researches publicly critiqued the source code of an extension. it would be better than nothing

Comment: Installing a browser extension is not that much different from installing other third party software, i.e. the risks of trust are the same. Does this answer your question? [How an experienced user decides a download is safe?](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/82239/how-an-experienced-user-decides-a-download-is-safe)

Comment: @stevec your question basically boils down to "should I trust X".Even if some researchers were to look at X and say's it's not a trojan, the developer can always trojanise it via an update.

Comment: @yeah_well I'm not so sure it's that futile. Suppose I devep an extension, keep the code in a public github repo, and have a checksum on it, then I think it can be examined publicly and confirmed by Google to be the exact same as the git commit (via the checksum). Also, the history of the developer would certainly help. An analogy: an ebay seller with 5000 sales and 99.9% positive rating *could* scam you, but you'd be more confident buying from them than someone who had no sales. Developers' info could offer analogous clues. note: I'm not expecting perfection, just don't want to give up

Comment: @yeah_well I changed the wording of the title so it doesn't sound like I'm after a *definitive* method, but would be glad to hear of methods that help however imperfect

Comment: Checksums are not a security control. They are too easily manipulated. They are a download integrity control.

Comment: The answers in the duplicate are directly relatable to your question, because, as Steffan said, there is no difference between a stand-alone binary and a browser extension. And the methods, and limitations for assurance, are the same.

Comment: @schroeder those "answers" don't so much as mention chrome extensions. Imagine someone asks "how do I pilot a hovercraft" and you point them to some frivolous "how do I drive a vehicle". Technically the first is a subset of the second. But those answers are probably going to be too general to be useful, as is the case with this question and it's "duplicate".

Comment: Steffan and I have explained why the duplicate is diectly relevant. .