# How am I supposed to trust binaries "submitted by anyone"?

Tags: windows, web-browser, chromium

I finally found a Chromium fork which appears to have made a serious effort to remove all the Google cancer. Sadly, I see this: https://ungoogled-software.github.io/ungoogled-chromium-binaries/

> IMPORTANT: These binaries are provided by anyone who are willing to build and submit them. Because these binaries are not necessarily reproducible, authenticity cannot be guaranteed. For your consideration, each download page lists the GitHub user that submitted those binaries.

I just can't see how I would be able to trust this. I'm more than paranoid enough even when they promise that it's super secure and they use a provably safe way to build them and blablabla... but these guys are going out of their way to point out how insecure it is.

I just can't trust this. But it appears to be the only semi-privacy-friendly Chrome fork.

I have zero trust in "Brave" and similar after all their privacy-disrespecting nonsense.

Is there really *no* way for me to safely view HTML pages in "the biggest rendering engine" on my computer without installing spyware (Chrome and its skins) or likely installing malware? Is there really no "solid" open source project which takes Chromium's code, rips out all the privacy-destroying madness and provides trustworthy binaries?

(Building them locally is not an option, and just the thought of explaining why makes me exhausted. Please don't suggest that.)

Comment: The initial question is essentially the "how to trust" question as already asked and answered in [How an experienced user decides a download is safe?](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/82239/how-an-experienced-user-decides-a-download-is-safe). The rest of the question is basically complaining that no one who you already trust creates the software you want.

Comment: @Ziad Be kind. Steffen has a very valid point, and I agree with it.

Comment: @Ziad Basically, if you want to use software written by other people, you'll have to trust *someone*. Which you refuse to do. So now you can either write all your own software, or live with the fact that you in today's world, you have no privacy.

Comment: Questions of the type "is there a product/service that does X?" are off-topic. Your main question is whether there is a Chromium build that you would accept. The rest of your questions appear to be rhetorical complaints. As for your title question, the duplicate addresses it.